# How to properly concatenate string on a function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation

```
function recent_posts_function() {

$call_number = the_field('call_number');
$book_author = the_field('book_author');
$publisher = the_field('publisher');
$edition = the_field('edition');
$description = the_field('description');
$subjects = the_field('subjects');

query_posts(array('post_type' => 'model', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'showposts' => 5));   
if (have_posts()) :
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo
        '<div class="book-list-section">'
            '<h3>' .$call_number '</h3>'                
        '</div>';
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();  
}
```

---

This is wordpress but my problem is I cant properly concatenate the html code and echo it. Please help me, I search and tried but still don't know...

---

```
function recent_posts_function() {  

 query_posts(array('post_type' => 'model', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'showposts' => 5));   
 if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        echo 
        '<div class="book-list-section">
            <h3>'.the_field(call_number).'</h3>
            <p><span>'.get_the_title().'</span></p>
            <br  class="clear" />
            <p>' .the_field('book_author').'</p>
            <br class="clear" />
            <p>' .the_field('publisher').'</p>
            <p>' .the_field('edition'). '</p>
            <p>' .the_field('description').'</p>
            <br class="clear" />
            <p>' .the_field('subjects'). '</p>
        </div>';
    endwhile;
 endif;
 wp_reset_query();    
 }
```

it's working but it's not inside the div... why is that? "get_the_title()" only is the one that is in the DIV... what's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is ACF

`the_field()` directly echoes the field value

Use `get_field()` within your echo block.

---

Also `get_field()` should be used inside the loop, you are using it outside at in your question

Comment: @Ghost, Glad you got it working mate. Max thanks for helping out. **+1**

Comment: Make sure you use `get_field()` inside the loop as well. :)

Answer (score 5):

You have some unneccesary quotes around and missed a concatenate operator after the `$call_number` variable.

The right way...

```
echo '<div class="book-list-section"><h3>'.$call_number.'</h3></div>';
```

Comment: Seems like your `have_posts()` is returning false and that's why it is not getting printed.

Comment: I directly and replaced the .$call_number with the_field('call_number') and it printed but its not in the proper tag.
I used firebug and it outside <h3> tag.. why is that?

Comment: "1"
<div class="book-list-section">
<h3></h3>
</div>

this is the outcome kindly help again... hehe